# Java - Accessing component information

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

So I have this class:

```
public class setting{
    JLabel label;
    Component main;
    JButton set, reset;

    setting(String s, Component b){
        this.label = new JLabel(s);
        this.main = b;
        this.set = new JButton("Set");
        this.reset = new JButton("Reset");
    }

    public void add(JPanel b) {
        b.add(this.label);
        b.add(this.main);
        b.add(this.set);
        b.add(this.reset);
    }
}
```

How would I be able to access this.main 's information? For example:

```
JSlider speed = new JSlider(0, 80); speed.setValue(0);
setting speedSett = new setting("speed", speed);
speedSett.main.getValue(); //This doesn't work
```

Is there anyway to access the information inside of the setting class the way I have this setup? I would like this class to accept different types of components, so simply setting it to JSlider won't do it for me.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know it's JSlider, cast it and use it:

```
JSlider speed = new JSlider(0, 80); speed.setValue(0);
setting speedSett = new setting("speed", speed);
if (speeSett.getMain() instanceof JSlider) {
  JSlider slider = (JSlider) speedSett.getMain(); // Recommend to access from getter instead of direct access
  slider.getValue();
}
```

Comment: Glad it helps you